# javascript code inside php is not able to access the html element. document.getElementById is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

`document.getElementById("n")` in the script inside php is not able to access the paragraph with `id="n"` in html.
The inner html of the paragraph is not being changed.
I also tried with jQuery but it was not able to change the `innerHTML` either.

```
<?php
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $servername="localhost";
    $database="mydb";
    $conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
    if(!($conn)){
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql="select passenger from place where source='chennai' and destination='bengaluru'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("n").innerHTML="Do Something";</script>';
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<html>
    <head lang="en-us">
        <title>Cards</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo_css.css">
    </head>    
    <body>
        <p id="n"></p>
        <div class="container" id="con">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-content waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
                    <h1 class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4" id="content"></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-reveal">
                    <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Passengers<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's because the js generated by php is executed before the rest of the age is loaded. If you put it underneath the html-block it should work.

Comment: ..and if you are already using jQuery you can use `$(document).ready()` to wait for the rest of the page to be loaded and ready to access. Or use a  vanilla js approach like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Comment: where is the javascript code?  only php and html is listed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for `document.getElementById('n')` returning nothing is, that it's executed before the rest of the html (including the element you are trying to get) is loaded.

So you got several options:

1. Place your javascript underneath the html (best before the closing `</html>`).
   That way it will be executed *after* element is loaded into the DOM.
2. Use a function that fires when the DOM is loaded and place your js code in there.

2.1. One way to do that is to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("n").innerHTML="Do Something";
}
```

2.2. Some vanilla JS ways are described in that SO-Post:
[pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)